# What's a Sewing Matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, topology, graphene

I'm reading a paper on graphene that talks about these sewing matrices, but I don't understand their definition.

Upon researching it on the internet, I've found the term in other papers, so I assume it is a common object in the field.

In the paper I'm reading, it is mentioned when speaking about the graphene symmetries. Does anyone know what they are, and, if you do, can you explain me or refer me to someplace you learned about it please?

Comment: Link to abstract page of paper? Which page?

Comment: Of the paper where I read it? Here https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.12376